# Unable to get .env variables to hide api key

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I am having trouble using the process.env to hide an api key.  The process seems pretty straight forward, so I'm not really sure what's happening.  If I plug the api key into the url it works, but when I use the .env variable it doesn't work.  I've tried to console.log (process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY) and it comes up undefined.

I'm using JS, express, and node.

.env file:

```
WEATHER_API_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
```

app.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const rp = require("request-promise");
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");


app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.get("/results", (req, res) => {
  let query = req.query.search;
  let weatherApiKey = process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY;
  let weatherUrl =
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" +
    query +
    "&appid=" +
    weatherApiKey;
  rp(weatherUrl)
    .then((body) => {
      let data = JSON.parse(body);
      res.render("results", { data: data });
      console.log("DOTENV", process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY);

    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Weather App is listening on PORT:", PORT);
});
```

Comment: Is the quote and semicolon a copy-paste error or what's actually in your .env?

Comment: Is the .env file in the *root* of your project? Does `console.log(process.env)` print anything?

Comment: Ah, that was the problem.  It wasn't in the root of my project. Thank you Michael Rodriguez!